# Angular 8.2 + Firebase: `ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js` errors near the end of `ng build --prod` fails the process

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, compiler-errors

First time asking a question here and likely not my last.

Problem: The `ng-build --prod` process cannot finish and errors out in my Angular 8.2.14 app. I am using Firebase and have been able to set it up in my project to a point where I'm receiving the data and passing it to the HTML. When trying to build for production so I can deploy it to Heroku, I receive multiple `ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js` errors with Firebase related things not found in a Firebase library mentioned in them.

```
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js 28:2969-2998
"export 'FirebaseNameOrConfigToken' (imported as 'i13') was not found in '@angular/fire'
    at HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency._getErrors (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/dependencies/HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.js:109:11)
    at HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.getErrors (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/dependencies/HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.js:68:16)
    at Compilation.reportDependencyErrorsAndWarnings (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1425:22)
    at hooks.finishModules.callAsync.err (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1221:10)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:42:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at Compilation.finish (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1216:28)
    at hooks.make.callAsync.err (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:662:17)
    at _done (eval at create (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:9:1)
    at _err1 (eval at create (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:36:22)
    at _addModuleChain (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1148:12)
    at processModuleDependencies.err (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1060:9)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
//----------
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js 28:3098-3127
"export 'FirebaseNameOrConfigToken' (imported as 'i13') was not found in '@angular/fire'
    at HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency._getErrors (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/dependencies/HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.js:109:11)
    at HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.getErrors (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/dependencies/HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.js:68:16)
    at Compilation.reportDependencyErrorsAndWarnings (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1425:22)
    at hooks.finishModules.callAsync.err (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1221:10)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:42:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at Compilation.finish (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1216:28)
    at hooks.make.callAsync.err (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:662:17)
    at _done (eval at create (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:9:1)
    at _err1 (eval at create (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:36:22)
    at _addModuleChain (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1148:12)
    at processModuleDependencies.err (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1060:9)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
//----------
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js 28:6418-6447
"export 'FirebaseNameOrConfigToken' (imported as 'i13') was not found in '@angular/fire'
    at HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency._getErrors (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/dependencies/HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.js:109:11)
    at HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.getErrors (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/dependencies/HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.js:68:16)
    at Compilation.reportDependencyErrorsAndWarnings (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1425:22)
    at hooks.finishModules.callAsync.err (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1221:10)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:42:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at Compilation.finish (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1216:28)
    at hooks.make.callAsync.err (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:662:17)
    at _done (eval at create (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:9:1)
    at _err1 (eval at create (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:36:22)
    at _addModuleChain (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1148:12)
    at processModuleDependencies.err (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1060:9)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
//----------
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js 28:2928-2952
"export 'FirebaseOptionsToken' (imported as 'i13') was not found in '@angular/fire'
    at HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency._getErrors (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/dependencies/HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.js:109:11)
    at HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.getErrors (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/dependencies/HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.js:68:16)
    at Compilation.reportDependencyErrorsAndWarnings (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1425:22)
    at hooks.finishModules.callAsync.err (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1221:10)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:42:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at Compilation.finish (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1216:28)
    at hooks.make.callAsync.err (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:662:17)
    at _done (eval at create (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:9:1)
    at _err1 (eval at create (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:36:22)
    at _addModuleChain (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1148:12)
    at processModuleDependencies.err (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1060:9)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
//----------
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js 28:3068-3092
"export 'FirebaseOptionsToken' (imported as 'i13') was not found in '@angular/fire'
    at HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency._getErrors (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/dependencies/HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.js:109:11)
    at HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.getErrors (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/dependencies/HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.js:68:16)
    at Compilation.reportDependencyErrorsAndWarnings (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1425:22)
    at hooks.finishModules.callAsync.err (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1221:10)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:42:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at Compilation.finish (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1216:28)
    at hooks.make.callAsync.err (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:662:17)
    at _done (eval at create (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:9:1)
    at _err1 (eval at create (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:36:22)
    at _addModuleChain (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1148:12)
    at processModuleDependencies.err (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1060:9)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
//----------
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js 28:6031-6055
"export 'FirebaseOptionsToken' (imported as 'i13') was not found in '@angular/fire'
    at HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency._getErrors (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/dependencies/HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.js:109:11)
    at HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.getErrors (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/dependencies/HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.js:68:16)
    at Compilation.reportDependencyErrorsAndWarnings (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1425:22)
    at hooks.finishModules.callAsync.err (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1221:10)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:42:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at Compilation.finish (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1216:28)
    at hooks.make.callAsync.err (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:662:17)
    at _done (eval at create (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:9:1)
    at _err1 (eval at create (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:36:22)
    at _addModuleChain (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1148:12)
    at processModuleDependencies.err (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1060:9)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
//----------
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js 28:3134-3157
"export 'RealtimeDatabaseURL' (imported as 'i13') was not found in '@angular/fire'
    at HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency._getErrors (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/dependencies/HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.js:109:11)
    at HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.getErrors (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/dependencies/HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.js:68:16)
    at Compilation.reportDependencyErrorsAndWarnings (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1425:22)
    at hooks.finishModules.callAsync.err (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1221:10)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:42:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at Compilation.finish (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1216:28)
    at hooks.make.callAsync.err (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:662:17)
    at _done (eval at create (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:9:1)
    at _err1 (eval at create (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:36:22)
    at _addModuleChain (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1148:12)
    at processModuleDependencies.err (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1060:9)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
//----------
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js 28:2902-2925
"export '_firebaseAppFactory' (imported as 'i13') was not found in '@angular/fire'
    at HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency._getErrors (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/dependencies/HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.js:109:11)
    at HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.getErrors (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/dependencies/HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.js:68:16)
    at Compilation.reportDependencyErrorsAndWarnings (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1425:22)
    at hooks.finishModules.callAsync.err (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1221:10)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:42:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at Compilation.finish (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1216:28)
    at hooks.make.callAsync.err (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:662:17)
    at _done (eval at create (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:9:1)
    at _err1 (eval at create (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:36:22)
    at _addModuleChain (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1148:12)
    at processModuleDependencies.err (/Users/sean.swanson/Desktop/Swan/dev/break-trainer/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1060:9)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
```

I am fairly new to Angular and used the CLI to generate my project as well as to create the components within. I've tried removing my node_modules folder and did an `npm install` in case it was a caching issue. I've followed guidance to install @angular/compiler and @angular/compiler-cli to 6.1.1 per some kind of related issues in https://github.com/ngx-rocket/generator-ngx-rocket/issues/366 but no luck.

Any insight here would be helpful! Thank you for reading.

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "break-trainer",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.13.4",
    "npm": "3.10.10"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "heroku-postbuild": "ng build --prod"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.23",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "angularfire": "^2.3.0",
    "angularfire2": "^5.4.2",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "firebase": "^7.9.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.900.0-0 || ^0.900.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.23",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.23",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "enhanced-resolve": "^3.3.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^7.12.1",
    "fuzzy": "^0.1.3",
    "inquirer": "^6.2.2",
    "inquirer-autocomplete-prompt": "^1.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try downgrading your @angular/fire version to 5.4.2. Per the project's [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md), starting from 6.0.0-rc.0 (2020-01-30) -

- Support for Angular versions less than 9 has been dropped
- Support for Firebase versions less than 7.8 has been dropped
- Support for firebase-tools less than 7.12 has been dropped

After downgrading (or upgrading Angular to 9), I would also make sure firebase and angularfire versions are all compatible.

Comment: My `ng build --prod` succeeded after changing the version as you suggested! Thank you!